# SUM of COUNT with only certain variables

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum, partition

I have the below query that is returning results, but I'm needing certain variables to be excluded from the filled_orders column.

Entire query:

```
SELECT
    order_date,
    p_category,
    issue_group,
    srt_level,
    order_count,
    filled_orders,
    total_orders,
    round(100 *(order_count / total_orders), 1) AS monthly_metric
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            order_date,
            p_category,
            issue_group,
            srt_level,
            order_count,
            CASE
                WHEN srt_level = '80'  THEN order_count
                WHEN srt_level = '100' THEN SUM(order_count) OVER(
                    PARTITION BY order_date, issue_group, p_category
                )
            END AS filled_orders,
            total_orders
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    order_date,
                    p_category,
                    issue_group,
                    srt_level,
                    order_count,
                    SUM(order_count) OVER(
                        PARTITION BY order_date, issue_group, p_category
                    ) AS total_orders
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            order_date,
                            p_category,
                            CASE
                                WHEN ( issue_grp = 1 ) THEN '1'
                                ELSE '2/3 '
                            END AS issue_group,
                            srt   AS srt_level,
                            COUNT(*) AS order_count
                        FROM
                            database.tcon_mv
                        WHERE
                            order_date IN (
                                '201803'
                            )
                        GROUP BY
                            p_category,
                            CASE
                                WHEN ( issue_grp = 1 ) THEN '1'
                                ELSE '2/3 '
                            END,
                            srt,
                            order_date
                    )
            )
    )
ORDER BY
    order_date,
    p_category,
    issue_group
```

Part giving me the "issues":

```
... SELECT
                order_date,
                p_category,
                issue_group,
                srt_level,
                order_count,
                CASE
                    WHEN srt_level = '80'  THEN order_count
                    WHEN srt_level = '100' THEN SUM(order_count) OVER(
                        PARTITION BY order_date, issue_group, p_category
                    )
                END AS filled_orders,
                total_orders
            FROM ....
```

srt_level is a varchar column that only has 3 options as it's results (80, 100, and Late).  When srt_level = '100', I'm needing the count to only include the sum of the 80 and 100 rows.

A view of what is being returned by the complete query, with expected results written in red.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to sum only `order_count` values where `srt_level` is not `Late`. Then say is in your `sum`:

```
SELECT
    order_date,
    p_category,
    issue_group,
    srt_level,
    order_count,
    CASE
        WHEN srt_level = '80'  THEN order_count
        WHEN srt_level = '100' THEN 
            SUM(CASE WHEN srt_level != 'Late' THEN order_count END) OVER(
               PARTITION BY order_date, issue_group, p_category
            )
    END AS filled_orders,
    total_orders
FROM ....
```

Comment: perfect ... thanks! I knew it had to be simple, just couldn't get the correct coding done.